# Cache a particular image using .htaccess

Tags: cache

I would like to cache a particular image on my website i.e the background image.

So far i only see options that allow you to define the format type(png|jpg|ico) is there anyway to let the browser cache the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following to set far future expiration dates for all media files:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

and I'd recommend using it because it will help out on the bandwidth and speed front's but this code would allow you to set the expiry for a specific file.

```
<Files "test1.jpg">
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A60
</Files>
```